# Trouble with active record join tables that do not have any associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to filter out all the objects(photos) that are not in a scheduled post table. I have the sql statement working:

```
Select * from photos p left join scheduled_posts sp on sp.photo_url = p.url where p.trashed = false and sp.photo_url is null
```

I am trying to get this to work in rails using active record but the two tables are not associated with each-other and I having trouble using .join because of this and am getting an undefined method 'join' error. Here is my current code:

```
@objects = "#{@objects.table_name}".joins("left join scheduled_posts sp on sp.photo_url = p.url ").where("photo_url @> ?", nil)
```

Comment: `"#{@objects.table_name}"` is a string, and `#joins` is not a method on `String`. You need to call `#constantize` on the class string to get the class constant, which you can call `#joins` on. So, you'll need to figure out how to get the class name instead of the table name.

Comment: You should mark my answer as correct if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

`"#{@objects.table_name}"` is a string, and `#joins` is not a method on `String`. Instead of calling it on the table name, you need to convert the table name to the name of the model class, and then call `#constantize` on it to get the class constant, which you can call `#joins` on.

```rb
classify(@objects.table_name).constantize.joins # ...
```